# r sql multiple user specified variables

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, rodbc, rsqlite

I have variable that contains some numbers

```
  x1
  6589 
  11482
  13573
```

Another variable x2 contains

```
  x2
  110426
  163684
  169555
```

I am trying to pass these values as a variable in my sql statement in R . So far I am good if I pass one variable (x1 or x2)

```
 id = paste((df$x1),collapse = ",")
 id1= paste0("(", id, ")")
 id1

 example <- sqlQuery(myDB,"SELECT * FROM dbo.my_table WHERE COLUMN1 in", id1)
```

Not sure how to do this with two variables x1 and x2

```
example <- sqlQuery(myDB,"SELECT * FROM dbo.my_table 
                    WHERE COLUMN1 in", id1"
                    AND   COLUMN2 in", id2" )  ?????
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepare the string first.

I'm not 100% confident with R 
Just make sure all the space between keywords are there.

```
id1 = "(1,2,3)"
id2 = "(8,9,10)"
strQuery =  paste("SELECT * FROM dbo.my_table ",
                  "WHERE COLUMN1 in " , id1,
                  " AND  COLUMN2 in " , id2, sep = " ")
```

Then:

```
example <- sqlQuery(myDB , strQuery)
```